# the function run more times than it should

Tags: javascript, function, call

```
'use strict'
let turn =1;
let countx = 0;
let counto = 0;
function addx(id){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '<p>x</p>';
    turn = 0;
    newclick();
    countx++;
    checkWin();
}
function addo(id){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '<p>o</p>';
    turn = 1;
    newclick();
    counto++;
    checkWin();
}
function checkWin(){
    if(countx==3||counto==3){
        alert('you win');
    }
 }
function newclick(){
    if(turn==1){
        document.getElementById('leftTop').addEventListener("click",function (){addx('leftTop')});
        document.getElementById('centerTop').addEventListener("click",function (){addx('centerTop')});
        document.getElementById('rightTop').addEventListener("click",function (){addx('rightTop')});
        document.getElementById('leftCenter').addEventListener("click",function (){addx('leftCenter')});
        document.getElementById('centerCenter').addEventListener("click",function (){addx('centerCenter')});
        document.getElementById('rightCenter').addEventListener("click",function (){addx('rightCenter')});
        document.getElementById('leftBottom').addEventListener("click",function (){addx('leftBottom')});
        document.getElementById('centerBottom').addEventListener("click",function (){addx('centerBottom')});
        document.getElementById('rightBottom').addEventListener("click",function (){addx('rightBottom')});
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('leftTop').addEventListener("click",function (){addo('leftTop')});
        document.getElementById('centerTop').addEventListener("click",function (){addo('centerTop')});
        document.getElementById('rightTop').addEventListener("click",function (){addo('rightTop')});
        document.getElementById('leftCenter').addEventListener("click",function (){addo('leftCenter')});
        document.getElementById('centerCenter').addEventListener("click",function (){addo('centerCenter')});
        document.getElementById('rightCenter').addEventListener("click",function (){addo('rightCenter')});
        document.getElementById('leftBottom').addEventListener("click",function (){addo('leftBottom')});
        document.getElementById('centerBottom').addEventListener("click",function (){addo('centerBottom')});
        document.getElementById('rightBottom').addEventListener("click",function (){addo('rightBottom')});
    }
}
newclick();
```

```
on the first click - countx = 1; counto=0.
on the second click - countx = 2; counto=1.
on the third click - countx = 4; counto=3.


what i want to get is:
first click countx =1;counto=0.
second click countx=1;counto=1.
third click countx=2;counto1.
```

what i wanted is every click is to add 1 to each count when it is his turn.
this is tictacteo game, every click is should replace the event listener.

the function of x somehow called 4 times on the third click, what i get "on board" is 2x and 1o but the countx = 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addEventListener` adds a new **additional** event listener every time it's run. Use just one event listener instead of trying to replace the old one to make this work better. Replacing them is unnecessary.

The `turn` variable already tracks whose turn it is. So you can use something like the following.

```
function genericClick(id) {
    if (turn == 1) {
        // add an x
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '<p>x</p>';
        turn = 0;
        countx++;
    } else {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '<p>o</p>';
        turn = 1;
        counto++;
    }
    checkWin();
}
```